# Unity lens not included in global search

Tags: unity, python, application-development

I'm using the quickly unity lens template here http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/
It works quite all right, but even though i have set search_in_global to true the global search calls my lens's search function without the entered search parameter, thus it returns everything it can find:

```
class Meta:
    name = 'myLens'
    description = 'My Lens'
    search_hint = 'Search My Lens'
    icon = 'mylens.svg'
    search_on_blank=True
    search_in_global=True #doesn't seem to work
```

When i type in a global search my search function is not called with the entered phrases but with a blank string/null:

```
def search(self, search, results):
    print "searching for %s" % search
    #...
```

Can anyone help me out here?

---

Thanks for the quick reply! i added the proposed method like so:

```
def global_search(self, search, results):
    print "searching globally for %s" % search
    self.search(search, results)
```

unfortunally the output when i type anything in the global dash doesn't change a lot:

```
leopard2a5@Spieleknecht:~/Desktop/mylens$ quickly run
searching globally for 
searching for
```

Comment: search_in_global isn't actually a setting, where did you get that from?

Comment: Let me correct that, search_in_global isn't a setting in Singlet, it does exist if you're using GObject to build your lens/scope

Comment: Ok, this is sounding like a bug now, can you file it against https://bugs.launchpad.net/hello-unity along with the source files for your lens (if possible, it'll help me debug it)

Comment: Sorry, should be filed against https://bugs.launchpad.net/singlet not hello-unity, wrong project

Answer (score 2):

If you define a function called global_search(self, phrase, results), that will be called on global searches instead of the default search(self, phrase, results).  See if that gets the correct search phrase.

Comment: See my answer below :)

Comment: No idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Please file it as a bug against Singlet, and attach the sourcecode for your project so I can test it.  Thanks.